# Text-Wrapped Figures with CatchFileBetweenTags

Tags: graphics, wrapfig

I've been trying to develop a clutter-free workflow for writing the content of LaTeX documents, and have nearly achieved it using the `catchfilebetweentags` package (I can write the text in a separate minimal file and then call it into the LaTeX document structure at compile time). However, I cannot get it to behave with text-wrapped figures. Any time a figure is larger than the height of the text section contained between the tags, strange figure placement occurs.

Desired output: when a figure is defined in a text section too short to contain it, it should be allowed to flow into the following section, wrapping text around as needed.

With none of the following configurations have I been able to achieve this.

MWE input file: `document.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\CatchFileBetweenTags{\SectionA}{content.tex}{SectionA}
\CatchFileBetweenTags{\SectionB}{content.tex}{SectionB}
\begin{document}
\section*{Section A}
\SectionA
\section*{Section B}
\SectionB
\end{document}
```

Example 1: figure inside large text section in `content.tex`

```
%<*SectionA>
text
%</SectionA>
%<*SectionB>
text
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./graphics/example.png}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Caption here.}
  \label{example_wrap_figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
text
text
%</SectionB>
```

Output: Figure wraps correctly if the text section is large enough
[image]

Example 2: figure inside small text section in `content.tex`

```
%<*SectionA>
text
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./graphics/example.png}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Caption here.}
  \label{example_wrap_figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
%</SectionA>
%<*SectionB>
text
text
text
%</SectionB>
```

Output: entire Section B is wrapped to the left, and using the optional "number of narrow lines" `wrapfig` option does not help ([Prevent wrapfigure from wrapping the next section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120926/prevent-wrapfigure-from-wrapping-the-next-section)).
[image]

Example 3: figure in between sections in `document.tex`, not `content.tex`

```
\section*{Section A}
\SectionA
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./graphics/example.png}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Caption here.}
  \label{example_wrap_figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
\section*{Section B}
\SectionB
```

Output: same as Example 2.

Example 4: figure in between sections in `document.tex` in its own scope

```
\section*{Section A}
\SectionA
{
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./graphics/example.png}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Caption here.}
  \label{example_wrap_figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
}
\section*{Section B}
\SectionB
```

Output: forces figure to the end of the document.
[image]

I suspect, that `catchfilebetweentags` executes `SectionA` before it knows about `SectionB`. Is there any way to get the desired output? Alternately, is there any way to delay the execution of the graphic environment until after all the text sections have been evaluated, perhaps by running `latex` multiple times?